# Remove trailing commas in ruby string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following value in my params: "45,284"

How can I remove the the leading and trailing double quotes from my string?

The output that I should get is: 45,284

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? `45,284` does have a comma

Comment: I have to remove commas from the start and end of the string...That is " and "

Comment: You mean to say inverted commas?

Comment: Yes, need to remove " and " from the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to your `params[:userValues]` to make it suitable for `IN` clause in your query

```
"45,284".split(",").map(&:to_i) #=> [45, 248]
```

So for `params[:userValues]` it will be

```
user_values = params[:userValues].split(",").map(&:to_i)
```

Now the query will look like this

```
@user = User.where('is_active = ? and is_support_user = ? and id IN (?)', true, false, user_values).order(:user_name)
```

This will work, try it out

Answer (score 0):

```
class String
  def trim
    self.gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, '')
  end
end

"\"45,284\"".trim
```